# Oracle Undo tablespace users

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, users, tablespaces

How to get all the users using the undo tablespace and how much?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This shows you the amount of undo size used by each session that is currently active.

```
select s.sid, 
       s.username,
       sum(ss.value) / 1024 / 1024 as undo_size_mb
from  v$sesstat ss
  join v$session s on s.sid = ss.sid
  join v$statname stat on stat.statistic# = ss.statistic#
where stat.name = 'undo change vector size'
and s.type <> 'BACKGROUND'
and s.username IS NOT NULL
group by s.sid, s.username;
```

Answer (score 1):

Undo is not used by users directly but by statements which modify many database blocks.
Try to search for session which generates a lot of redo.

```
select sid, serial#, value from v$session join v$sesstat using(sid) 
where statistic# = (SELECT statistic# FROM v$statname WHERE name = 'redo size');
```

Or for active transactions:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(s.sid)||','||TO_CHAR(s.serial#) sid_serial,
       NVL(s.username, 'None') orauser,
       s.program,
       r.name undoseg,
       t.used_ublk * TO_NUMBER(x.value)/1024||'K' "Undo"
  FROM sys.v_$rollname    r,
       sys.v_$session     s,
       sys.v_$transaction t,
       sys.v_$parameter   x
 WHERE s.taddr = t.addr
   AND r.usn   = t.xidusn(+)
   AND x.name  = 'db_block_size'
```

Or look at the view V$UNDOSTAT.